# Check all the columns for whitespace

Tags: sql, teradata

I would like to check all the columns to see if there are any records that just return whitespaces. Currently, I'm checking it by doing:

`SELECT COLUMNNAME FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMNNAME = ''`

However, there are multiple tables that I need to check and each tables contains quite a lot of columns. I would much rather not check each individual columns at a time, is there a way to have a query that check all of the columns in a table?

Comment: Multiple ORed conditions? `where col1 = '' or col2 = '' or  ...`

Comment: True, I can do that. But I still want to see if there's a less tedious way of doing this as there are quite a lot of columns.

Answer (score 1):

You could just write a SQL statement that spits out the sql statement you are after. Sometimes I just dump the list of columns in excel and stitch together a sql statement in there when I'm feeling extra lazy.

```
WITH cteTable AS 
(
    SELECT columnid, columnname, tablename, databasename 
    FROM "DBC".ColumnsV 
    WHERE TableName = 'yourtablename' AND DatabaseName = 'yourdatabasename'
)
SELECT output 
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT CAST(1 AS INTEGER) AS myorder, 'SELECT * FROM ' || DatabaseName || '.' || TableName || ' WHERE ' AS output
    FROM cteTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT columnid, CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColumnId) > 1 THEN 'OR ' ELSE ' ' END || columnname || ' = '''''
    FROM cteTable
) sub 
ORDER BY myorder
```

This doesn't take into account field types or anything fancy like that, but it should get you in the ballpark